# Is there a reproductive barrier between Khoisan and other humans?

Tags: human-biology, ethnobiology, anthropology

I have heard in an ethnology lecture that more or less all human ethnicities interbreed without a barrier (rate of reproduction of fertile offspring) except the Khoisan + any other human ethnicities, where fertile offspring is less likely than when other humans interbreed (as a an anecdotic side note, there are rumors about Zulu men who prefer Khoisan women as second or third spouse in order not to produce too many kids). My question is if some can confirm or falsify this (any literature coverage)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the book "Genetic Nature/Culture: Anthropology and Science Beyond the Two-Culture Divide" edited by Alan H. Goodman, Deborah Heath, M. Susan Lindee. Page 205 states that that is a myth started by geneticist F Lenz of Gottingen that has been disproven.

Comment: Oh dear, which (FL) on top is a very dubious source, thank you for clarifying this!